# Schema.org <head> HTML markup: can I just use the meta tags?

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

So I was looking at Schema.org. Do I need to change my `<html>` tag to this

```html
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
```

or can I just use only the meta tags within my `<head></head>` block?

```html
<meta itemprop="name" content="The Name or Title Here">
<meta itemprop="description" content="This is the page description">
<meta itemprop="image" content="http://www.example.com/image.jpg">
```

Answer (score 9):

Properties need to belong to an item. You create an item with the `itemscope` attribute (and the `itemtype` attribute can give this item a type).

Without `itemscope`, your markup example is invalid.

It is possible to provide Microdata only within the `head` element, but it’s not recommended for two reasons:

- Microdata was intended to be used on your existing markup. While it can often make sense to include certain `meta`/`link` elements in the `head` ([with `itemref`, see an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22415563/1591669)), most of the content is typically in the `body`. If you only want to use elements within `head`, you would have to duplicate most your content. But if you want to go that route, you [might prefer to use JSON-LD](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/328711/63183).
- As `head` doesn’t allow the use of a grouping element (like `div`), it gets complex to express Microdata. You would have to use `itemref` for every property and misuse an element like `style` for every item (see [the first snippet in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31854211/1591669) as example).

Your example could look like this:

```html
<head>
  <style itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article" itemref="p1a p1b p1c"></style>
  <meta id="p1a" itemprop="name" content="The Name or Title Here">
  <meta id="p1b" itemprop="description" content="This is the page description">
  <link id="p1c" itemprop="image" href="http://www.example.com/image.jpg">
</head>
```

If you can use `itemscope` on the `head` element, it would be better:

```html
<head itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
  <meta itemprop="name" content="The Name or Title Here">
  <meta itemprop="description" content="This is the page description">
  <link itemprop="image" href="http://www.example.com/image.jpg">
</head>
```

But as soon as you need more than one item (which is typically the case, e.g., for the `Organization`/`Person` which is the `author` etc.), this doesn’t work anymore, and you would need a solution like in my first snippet.

Note that it’s allowed to use `meta`/`link` elements for Microdata within the `body` element. This makes it way easier, as you can use `div` elements for the `itemscope`. So even if you duplicate your content instead of marking up your existing content, it would be preferable to do this in the `body`:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
  <meta itemprop="name" content="The Name or Title Here">
  <meta itemprop="description" content="This is the page description">
  <link itemprop="image" href="http://www.example.com/image.jpg">
</div>
```

(I replaced the `meta` element for the `image` property with a `link` element, because [using `meta` is invalid for this purpose](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24659620/1591669).)

Comment: @insertusernamehere: Schema.org and Microdata are different things and projects, so no matter what Schema.org writes, it doesn’t affect what is/isn’t valid Microdata. (By the way, it would be valid in RDFa.) -- Schema.org’s statement about `WebPage` makes sense for consumers of the data (they have to work with invalid data), but, in my opinion, authors should not use `WebPage` implicitly; I recommend that authors follow the advice in the next sentence of the `WebPage` description: "We recommend explicit declaration […]"

Comment: Why misuse `<style>`? Is it not possible to just use `meta` with an empty content like this: `<meta content="" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article" itemref="p1a p1b p1c">` ?
(Validator won't say meh)

Comment: @LucianDavidescu: The `meta` element must have exactly one of these attributes: `name`, `itemprop`, `http-equiv`, `charset`.

Comment: Indeeed, sorry, i was quite confused. How about `<meta itemprop="hasPart" content="" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article" itemref="p1a p1b p1c">` ?

Comment: I realise that this may be confusing too I'm afraid. Better come up with an example of what I mean: https://pastebin.com/itaps2Ka

This validates and is parsed by Google structured data testing tool with just one warning, that seems to be an issue of double attribution (the first - proper, the second - useless)

Comment: @LucianDavidescu: Yes, this works for child/embedded items, but it doesn’t work for top-level items (which can’t have an `itemprop` attribute).

Answer (score 1):

The section about [Microdata](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/microdata.html#microdata) on [whatwg.org](https://whatwg.org) doesn't mention `meta`-elements in the `head`-element of a HTML document explicitly. In conclusion you need `itemscope` to have valid markup.

If you take a look at the description at [schema.org](https://schema.org/WebPage) you'll find this section about *WebPages*:

> Every web page is implicitly assumed to be declared to be of type WebPage, so the various properties about that webpage, such as breadcrumb may be used. We recommend explicit declaration if these properties are specified, but if they are found outside of an itemscope, they will be assumed to be about the page.

The interesting part is this:

> […] if they [the properties] are found outside of an `itemscope`, **they will be assumed to be about the page.**

According to this you don't need to `itemscope` to the `html`-element. But it reads more like a suggestion then a definite specification.

---

You can see this behavior also in Google's [Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool). When you run this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta itemprop="name" content="The Name or Title Here">
        <meta itemprop="description" content="This is the page description">
        <meta itemprop="image" content="http://www.example.com/image.jpg">
    </head>
</html>
```

… you'll find that it doesn't capture any data. It'll start capturing data, as soon as you add `itemscope` resulting in an *Unspecified Type* without any error:

[image: Screenshot from Google's tool]

Using `itemtype="http://schema.org/Article"` will fail or at least throw errors as too few properties are given for type `Article`.

---

All different types can be found on the [WebPage overview](http://schema.org/WebPage) on scheme.org. Maybe one is suitable for the whole page.

Comment: Awesome the more simple and effective the better :) I don't think it is easy for sites to modify their <html> tag anyway since switching between article blog website video etc is why allot of sites don't use it i think and stick to opengraph.

Comment: @C0nw0nk Even for Open Graph you actually need `<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">`, but I think it's not needed by most parsers. See [ogp.me](http://ogp.me).

Comment: You said `if only itemscope is present with an undefined type.` Can you give a example of a undefined type would that be useable as universal for all types like article, videos, images, blogs etc.

Comment: @C0nw0nk I've updated the answer with some more informations, regarding your questions.

Answer (score 1):

According to the given example from [scheme.org](http://schema.org/docs/gs.html#microdata_itemprop), yes both are compulsory for Google.

To validate whether your data is being captured properly you can use this tool:

[Structured data testing tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool)

By using the tool above you can see that if you omit `itemtype="http://schema.org/Article"` the data will not get captured.

Comment: Thanks for the information :) is there a universal schema attribute i can apply that will work for website, article , videos , images. The itemtype above is just for articles if i can apply one that functions for all would be fantastic.

Comment: The most common one would be http://schema.org/CreativeWork, if possible try to narrow things down. :)

Comment: Also mind you that schema microdata is getting outdated due to it being rather messy to implement as it interferes with the html. Google has recommended we used JSON-LD instead, https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data. This is much cleaner to implement

Answer (score 0):

You can safely use `<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">`. This allows you to define itemprop's inside `<head>` element.

Google Rich Test Snippets and w3 validator, both validate this approach as I have already tested it.